# Order by Date not functioning as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I am writing a PL/SQL procedure that reports information on activity by date. Where I order by on the raw Date (type is date) field the order by does not seem to sort properly. if I convert it using to_char it works; but to_char can have its own issues. Why is this happening?

I've tried order by on the database field PT.BEGIN_DATE and I've tried it with the to_char shown below.

```
select  PT.BEGIN_DATE, PT.TRAN_TYPE || '/' || PT.TRAN_CODE as TRAN,
   PT.TRAN_NBR, PT.MODULE_NAME, PT.MENU_OPTN_NAME,  
   TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(PT.END_DATE - PT.BEGIN_DATE, 'DAY')), 'FM00') || ':' ||
  TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(PT.END_DATE - PT.BEGIN_DATE, 'DAY')), 'FM00') || ':' ||
  TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(PT.END_DATE - PT.BEGIN_DATE, 'DAY')), 'FM00') as Elapsed,
  SU.USER_NAME, COALESCE(trim(IM.SKU_BRCD), ' '), COALESCE(trim(PT.CNTR_NBR),'  '), COALESCE(trim(PT.WAVE_NBR), ' '), COALESCE(trim(PT.PKT_CTRL_NBR), ' '), COALESCE(trim(PT.PKT_SEQ_NBR), ' '), 
  PT.NBR_UNITS, COALESCE(trim(LH1.LOCN_BRCD), ' ') as FROM_LOCN, COALESCE(trim(LH2.LOCN_BRCD), ' ') as TO_LOCN, COALESCE(trim(PT.OLD_STAT_CODE), ' '), COALESCE(trim(PT.NEW_STAT_CODE), ' '), 
  COALESCE(trim(PT.WKSTN_ID), ' '), PT.USER_ID, PT.END_DATE
from ACT_TRACK_TRAN PT
   left join SKU_MASTER IM on IM.SKU_ID = PT.SKU_ID
   left join LOCN_MASTER LH1 on LH1.LOCN_ID = PT.FROM_LOCN
   left join LOCN_MASTER LH2 on LH2.LOCN_ID = PT.TO_LOCN
   left join SEC_USER SU on SU.LOGIN_USER_ID = PT.USER_ID
   where pt.MASTER_ID = v_CD and PT.SKU_ID like v_SKUID and PT.USER_ID   
like v_USER and PT.PKT_CTRL_NBR like v_PKT and PT.CNTR_NBR Like v_CNTR 
   and trunc(PT.BEGIN_DATE) between trunc(v_START) and trunc(v_STOP)
   ORDER BY to_char(PT.BEGIN_DATE, 'yyyymmddhhmmss') ;
```

Results as show above:

```
Start Date/Time    
------------------- 
09/09/2019 10:09:09 
09/09/2019 10:09:23 
09/09/2019 10:09:27
```

Results when sorting on just PT_BEGIN_DATE

```
Start Date/Time     
------------------- 
09/09/2019 10:09:23 
09/09/2019 10:09:09 
09/09/2019 10:09:27
```

Comment: just use `ORDER BY PT.BEGIN_DATE`, that's of type `date`, isn't that? (*why are you tring to convert to a string ?*)

Comment: I tried that and got the wrong results as shown above

Comment: Try `ORDER BY to_char(PT.BEGIN_DATE, 'yyyymmddhh24mmss')` or even better simply `ORDER BY PT.BEGIN_DATE`. Why do you use `TO_CHAR`?

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(NUMTODSINTERVAL(PT.END_DATE - PT.BEGIN_DATE, 'DAY'), '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}') as Elapsed` would be shorter.

Comment: `COALESCE(trim(IM.SKU_BRCD), ' ')` is fairly useless. Use `trim(IM.SKU_BRCD)`

Comment: When you test this, is your NLS_DATE_FORMAT using HH or HH24? I suspect (and as Wernfried hinted) you're mixing AM and PM times and can't tell the difference when you look at the output. i.e. with the plain-date version you're seeing 10:09:23 AM, then 10:09:09 PM. We can't see your raw data to verify though.

Comment: I will try the suggestion on the elapsed - thank you.

Comment: I use the coalesce for this particular purpose because I am using rpad later on to maintain column spacing and rpad on Null is not the same as rpad on a space

Comment: I didn't think about the ampm issue - I will try that now.

Comment: I thought for sure it was AM/PM issue, but that gave the same erroneous results. All my times are in the am if that helps

Comment: NLS set to DD-MON-RR

Comment: Thank you all for your help, but I have to send this source back to the code locker for review. So I will leave it as is for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted order-by clause you're converting the date to a string using the model `'yyyymmddhhmmss'`. That is using the month twice - it should be `'yyyymmddhhmiss'` (`mi` for minutes, not `mm`, which is month); or preferably `'yyyymmddhh24miss'` to avoid AM/PM confusion. (There is no reason to convert to a string for ordering here, but I think you only did it to investigate why it appeared wrong with a plain date...)

As the output you have shown doesn't match your stated NLS settings you must be converting the result of the query to a string elsewhere. Presumably you made the same mistake in the format model there too.

So when you ordered simply by the date value (as you should), not by its string representation, the results were actually in the correct order; but because you later also displayed the wrong value for the minutes it only *appeared* to be wrong.

Quick demo with both order-by options:

```
with pt (begin_date) as (
  select to_date('2019-09-09 10:01:23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all
  select to_date('2019-09-09 10:02:09', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all
  select to_date('2019-09-09 10:03:27', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select begin_date,
  to_char(begin_date, 'yyyymmddhhmmss') as wrong_1,
  to_char(begin_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss') as wrong_2,
  to_char(begin_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as right_3
from pt
order by begin_date;

BEGIN_DATE          WRONG_1        WRONG_2             RIGHT_3            
------------------- -------------- ------------------- -------------------
2019-09-09 10:01:23 20190909100923 09/09/2019 10:09:23 09/09/2019 10:01:23
2019-09-09 10:02:09 20190909100909 09/09/2019 10:09:09 09/09/2019 10:02:09
2019-09-09 10:03:27 20190909100927 09/09/2019 10:09:27 09/09/2019 10:03:27
```

When ordered by the plain date, the `wrong_2` values appear to be in the wrong order, but the `right_3` shows the order is actually correct.

```
with ...
select begin_date,
  to_char(begin_date, 'yyyymmddhhmmss') as wrong_1,
  to_char(begin_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss') as wrong_2,
  to_char(begin_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as right_3
from pt
order by to_char(begin_date, 'yyyymmddhhmmss');

BEGIN_DATE          WRONG_1        WRONG_2             RIGHT_3            
------------------- -------------- ------------------- -------------------
2019-09-09 10:02:09 20190909100909 09/09/2019 10:09:09 09/09/2019 10:02:09
2019-09-09 10:01:23 20190909100923 09/09/2019 10:09:23 09/09/2019 10:01:23
2019-09-09 10:03:27 20190909100927 09/09/2019 10:09:27 09/09/2019 10:03:27
```

When ordered by the (incorrect) string, the `wrong_2` values appear to be in the correct order, but the `right_3` shows the order is actually wrong.

Comment: That's it. I was so focused on the order by I didn't even look at that. Thanks

Comment: Perfect explanation!! Kudos to you brother!!

Comment: @DocMac - if this is indeed the correct answer to the question you posted, please don't forget to mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Convert into Date before sorting it like..
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, PT.BEGIN_DATE) ASC

Comment: That isn't Oracle syntax. And there's no point converting from a date to a string, and then back to a date.